# Count matching letters once

Tags: javascript, function, count, match

I'm creating a kid's learning tool that has a form which matches 4 letters to a word.

I want to count the number of character matches in a word. But it counts duplicates of letters as 2 instead of 1. For example if the word is **"loot"**, and the user submits **"flop"**, the matching letters are **3** instead of **2**, because it's counting **"o"** twice. How do I fix this? Many thanks

```
       function countMatching(str1, str2) {
            var c = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {

              if (str2.includes(str1[i]))
                c += 1;
                
            }
            matchingLetters = c;
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made an alternative version of @cmgchess' answer, which creates an array of the actual solution of letters to still guess, and removes each letter as it is encountered in the entered solution.

```js
let matchingLetters;

function countMatching(str1, str2) {
            var c = 0;
            str1Arr = str1.split('');
            
            for (var i = 0; i < str2.length; i++) {

              if (str1Arr.includes(str2[i])) {
                c += 1;
                str1Arr.splice(str1Arr.indexOf(str2[i]), 1);
              }
                
            }
            matchingLetters = c;
          }
          
          
countMatching('loot', 'boot') 
console.log(matchingLetters)
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue!

Comment: how about interchanging str1 and str2 in OP's solution

Comment: I toyed with that idea as well, but if the actual solution has no duplicates and your one does, it'll miscount too. Say the solution is `lost` and you enter `boot`, it'll wrongly return 3

Comment: @fravolt aha good catch

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach using Sets.
I converted the string into a set and back to an array
so if `str1` is `loot` then `str1Set` will be `['l','o','t']`. The rest is the same

```js
let matchingLetters;

function countMatching(str1, str2) {
            var c = 0;
            str1Set = [...new Set([...str1])]
            str2Set = [...new Set([...str2])]
            
            for (var i = 0; i < str1Set.length; i++) {

              if (str2Set.includes(str1Set[i]))
                c += 1;
                
            }
            matchingLetters = c;
          }
          
          
countMatching('loot', 'flop') 
console.log(matchingLetters)
```

Comment: I think if someone guesses `boon` while the result is `loot`, you'd also want to return 2, because both o's are correct. Maybe splitting loot and splicing once letters have been encountered would prevent this.

Comment: Thank you. This works for removing the duplicate count. However now if the correct guess is 'loot', the match is 3 not 4: https://jsfiddle.net/g67dbx3m/2/
Seems it's reversed the issue

Comment: i misunderstood your question. i thought you need to remove duplicate counts

Comment: I made an alternative version of your answer which uses an array of solution letters and removes each if it's encountered

Answer (score 0):

```
function countMatching(str1, str2) {
            var c = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {

              if (str2.includes(str1[i]))
                  if (!c.includes(str1[i])) c.push(str1[i])
                
            }
            matchingLetters = c.length;
          }
```

I'm writing on a tab, so there might be mistakes

What I did is that I made c to be a list that contains each character shared between the two strings. And a new character is pushed into c only if the character doesn't exist in it, hence making it a list of unique characters.

Then you can get the length of the list or you can even use the list for other purposes